# Trying to attach my Token to the machine and getting this BIG huge error command line:

Tags: command-line, apt

im trying to attach my Token to the machine and getting this BIG huge error command line:

```
sudo pro attach <*mytoken*>
[sudo] senha para guinomo: 
Unexpected error(s) occurred.
For more details, see the log: /var/log/ubuntu-advantage.log
To file a bug run: ubuntu-bug ubuntu-advantage-tools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 1704, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 1834, in main
    return_value = args.action(args, cfg=cfg, extra_args=extra_args)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 255, in new_f
    return f(args, cfg=cfg, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 200, in new_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 184, in new_f
    retval = f(*args, cfg=cfg, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 1303, in action_attach
    actions.attach_with_token(cfg, token=token, allow_enable=allow_enable)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/actions.py", line 62, in attach_with_token
    new_machine_token = contract_client.add_contract_machine(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/util.py", line 92, in decorator
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/contract.py", line 92, in add_contract_machine
    activity_info = self._get_activity_info()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/contract.py", line 425, in _get_activity_info
    "desktop": system.is_desktop(),
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/system.py", line 397, in is_desktop
    for package in apt.get_installed_packages():
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/apt.py", line 708, in get_installed_packages
    out, _ = system.subp(["apt", "list", "--installed"])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/system.py", line 703, in subp
    out, err = _subp(
               ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/system.py", line 652, in _subp
    raise exceptions.ProcessExecutionError(
uaclient.exceptions.ProcessExecutionError: Falha ao executar comando 'apt list --installed' [exit(100)]. Mensagem: 
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

E: Tipo 'sudo' não é conhecido na linha 1 na lista de fontes /etc/apt/sources.list.d/element-io.list
E: A lista de fontes não pode ser lida.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/version.py", line 55, in get_last_known_candidate
    candidate_version = get_pkg_candidate_version(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/apt.py", line 315, in get_pkg_candidate_version
    with PreserveAptCfg(get_apt_pkg_cache) as cache:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/apt.py", line 261, in __enter__
    return self.apt_func()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/apt.py", line 277, in get_apt_pkg_cache
    return apt_pkg.Cache(None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
apt_pkg.Error: E:Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/element-io.list, E:The list of sources could not be read.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pro", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('ubuntu-advantage-tools==8001', 'console_scripts', 'ubuntu-advantage')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 1774, in wrapper
    _warn_about_new_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 1625, in _warn_about_new_version
    new_version = version.check_for_new_version()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/version.py", line 77, in check_for_new_version
    candidate = get_last_known_candidate()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/version.py", line 64, in get_last_known_candidate
    if candidate_version is not None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'candidate_version' where it is not associated with a value
guinomo@Guinom0-DESKTOP:~$ ^C
guinomo@Guinom0-DESKTOP:~$ sudo pro attach <*mytoken>

Unexpected error(s) occurred.
For more details, see the log: /var/log/ubuntu-advantage.log
To file a bug run: ubuntu-bug ubuntu-advantage-tools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 1704, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 1834, in main
    return_value = args.action(args, cfg=cfg, extra_args=extra_args)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 255, in new_f
    return f(args, cfg=cfg, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 200, in new_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 184, in new_f
    retval = f(*args, cfg=cfg, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 1303, in action_attach
    actions.attach_with_token(cfg, token=token, allow_enable=allow_enable)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/actions.py", line 62, in attach_with_token
    new_machine_token = contract_client.add_contract_machine(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/util.py", line 92, in decorator
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/contract.py", line 92, in add_contract_machine
    activity_info = self._get_activity_info()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/contract.py", line 425, in _get_activity_info
    "desktop": system.is_desktop(),
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/system.py", line 397, in is_desktop
    for package in apt.get_installed_packages():
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/apt.py", line 708, in get_installed_packages
    out, _ = system.subp(["apt", "list", "--installed"])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/system.py", line 703, in subp
    out, err = _subp(
               ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/system.py", line 652, in _subp
    raise exceptions.ProcessExecutionError(
uaclient.exceptions.ProcessExecutionError: Falha ao executar comando 'apt list --installed' [exit(100)]. Mensagem: 
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

E: Tipo 'sudo' não é conhecido na linha 1 na lista de fontes /etc/apt/sources.list.d/element-io.list
E: A lista de fontes não pode ser lida.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/version.py", line 55, in get_last_known_candidate
    candidate_version = get_pkg_candidate_version(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/apt.py", line 315, in get_pkg_candidate_version
    with PreserveAptCfg(get_apt_pkg_cache) as cache:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/apt.py", line 261, in __enter__
    return self.apt_func()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/apt.py", line 277, in get_apt_pkg_cache
    return apt_pkg.Cache(None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
apt_pkg.Error: E:Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/element-io.list, E:The list of sources could not be read.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pro", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('ubuntu-advantage-tools==8001', 'console_scripts', 'ubuntu-advantage')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 1774, in wrapper
    _warn_about_new_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/cli/__init__.py", line 1625, in _warn_about_new_version
    new_version = version.check_for_new_version()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/version.py", line 77, in check_for_new_version
    candidate = get_last_known_candidate()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uaclient/version.py", line 64, in get_last_known_candidate
    if candidate_version is not None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'candidate_version' where it is not associated with a value
```

any tips?
thank you, any help should be appreciated...

I try to upgrade my distro linux from - ubuntu canonical gnome - 23.01 mantic minoutaur and get a upgrade to ppa..
now they show-me im with v. 23.04 lunnar lobster.
im on my personal computer, at home.. x64.. trying to learn linux.. i migrated from windows =)

Comment: Ubuntu Pro is only supported on the LTS releases of Ubuntu.  22.10, 23.04 and 23.10 are not supported and it will not work on those releases.